# Azure DevOps - receive an email each time a comment is posted

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps, how can I create a rule that will notify me each time a comment is added to any work item?  Also, is there a way to have it where it only notifies for work items either assigned to me or I have commented on in the past?

Here is what I have so far, but it's not working.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments (discussion area) is History field behind the scenes so you can check if it changes (and also only what assigned to you):

[image]

Comment: I was under the impression 'History' contained changes for every fields. I've tested your solution and you're right, it only send for new comments. Strange that `Comment count` don't work. Thanks!